# QML Drawer doesn't work correctly on smartphone

Tags: android, qt, qml

There was such a strange behavior Drawer. On the Desktop, as well as on the emulator, it works correctly. However on my smartphone it does not work correctly. Incorrectness is as follows: If you do drag open then press the button the Drawer closes, the next pressing of the button does not open the Drawer.

**Work.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

WorkForm {

    property bool isOpened: false

    menuButton {
        onClicked: {
            console.log("isOpened: "+ isOpened);
            console.log("drawer.opened: "+ drawer.opened);
            if (isOpened){
                console.log("drawer close()");
                drawer.close();
            }
            else {
                console.log("drawer open()");
                drawer.open();
            }
        }
    }

    headerSize: 48

    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        dragMargin: 60
        y: headerSize
        width: 0.4 * parent.width
        height: parent.height  - headerSize
        clip: true

        Label {
            text: "Content goes here!"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
        onOpened: {
            console.log("drawer onOpened");
            isOpened = true;
        }
        onClosed: {
            console.log("drawer onClosed");
            isOpened = false;
        }

    }
}
```

**WorkForm.ui.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    id: uiWelcomeForm
    anchors.fill: parent

    property color headerColor: "#d73c3c"
    property int headerSize: 48
    property alias menuButton: menuButton

    Rectangle {
        id: menuRect
        height: headerSize //вставить всюду dpi
        color: headerColor
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right

        //Icon Hamburger
        Rectangle {
            id: iconHamburger
            width: headerSize
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            color: headerColor

            ....

            MouseArea {
                id: menuButton
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log example (last line: button was pressed but this is no reaction from Drawer):

```
.....   
D libSimpleApp_QML.so: qrc:/Work.qml:16 (onClicked): qml: drawer open()
D libSimpleApp_QML.so: qrc:/Work.qml:37 (onOpened): qml: drawer onOpened
D libSimpleApp_QML.so: qrc:/Work.qml:9 (onClicked): qml: isOpened: true
D libSimpleApp_QML.so: qrc:/Work.qml:10 (onClicked): qml: drawer.opened: false
D libSimpleApp_QML.so: qrc:/Work.qml:12 (onClicked): qml: drawer close()
D libSimpleApp_QML.so: qrc:/Work.qml:41 (onClosed): qml: drawer onClosed
D libSimpleApp_QML.so: qrc:/Work.qml:9 (onClicked): qml: isOpened: false
D libSimpleApp_QML.so: qrc:/Work.qml:10 (onClicked): qml: drawer.opened: false
D libSimpleApp_QML.so: qrc:/Work.qml:16 (onClicked): qml: drawer open()
```

Comment: Which Qt version? Have you checked if there's a bug report that's similar to what you're seeing?

Comment: Qt version: 5.10.1. Yes, firstly I try to find any question-answer with google (QTBUGS is searching with google)

Answer (score 0):

Use the closePolicy of the Popup (from which the drawer inherits) and set it to Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside